# jquery mobile pagecreate event for dialogs

Tags: jquery-mobile

Hi jQueryMobile has an event for on pagecreate but it doesn't work with the dialogs (dialog page embeded in the same page with `data-role="page"`)

```css
$(document).delegate("pagecreate", "#foo-dialog", function() {
    console.log("dialog-opened");
});
```

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this?

Comment: I had a similar issue but my mistake was that I delegated the event handler with a wrong selector. The tricky (and undocumented) thing is, that when you open a page as a dialog, it does not have `data-role="page"` but `data-role="dialog"`.

Answer (score 0):

I have working code where pagecreate/pageshow is being called when showing a dialog, maybe you have your JS in the wrong spot? If you AJAX transitioned to this page any JS in your head tags isn't pulled in.